# What is the English meaning of this verse?

Tags: quran-translation

I am trying to find out the English meaning of the verse underneath, Is there any special benefit if I practice this verse daily??

> fallaho khairul hafezao oha hua arhamur rahimin. fallaho khairul
>   hafezao ohallahu khairul razikkin. innallaha huyarrazzaku jul kkuyatil
>   matin.

Comment: Can you provide Arabic version of this, i.e write it with Arabic alphabet? It is hard to guess correct words with transliteration.

Comment: I do not have this in Arabic vertion. But I know this is a special doa to Allaha. Thank you very much for your reply,

Comment: These are different qur'an quotes which should clearly be distinguished by surah and verse number. Further this ttransliteration is horrible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First part of this praying is belong to Surah Yusuf, verse 64:
Arabic:
فَاللّهُ خَيْرٌ حَافِظًا وَهُوَ أَرْحَمُ الرَّاحِمِينَ

English:

> But Allah is the best Keeper, and He is the most Merciful of the
>   merciful ones.

Second part is belong to Surah Hajj, verse 58:

Arabic:

(وَ الّذِينَ هاجَرُوا فِى سَبِيلِ اللّهِ ثُمَّ قُتِلُوا أَوْ ماتُوا لَيَرْزُقَنَّهُمُ اللّهُ رِزْقاً حَسناً وَ إِنَّ اللّهَ لَهُوَ خَيْرُ الرّازِقينَ).(حج/58)

English:

1. > And (as for) those who fly in Allah's way and are then slain or die,
   >   Allah will most certainly grant them a goodly sustenance, and most
   >   surely Allah is the best Giver of sustenance

.

I try to understand last sentence of above quotes but I could not yet?

Imam Sadiq -peace be upon him- refers to first sentence of this praying in a special praying…

Answer (score 0):

The last (the third part ) verse is :
( إن الله هو الرزاق ذو القوة المتين)
الاية 58 من سورة الذاريات
Verse 58 Adh-Dhariyat 51
English translation :
( Indeed, it is Allah who is the {continual} provider,the Firm possessor of strength ).
Another translation by Yousif Ali
( For Allah is He Who gives ( all) sustenance ,- lord of Power -steadfast ( for ever ).

I see the question and I recognise the Aya so I send it to you